# C# Visual Studio 2012 does not produce a helpful compilation error when failing to return a value, while VS 2010 does

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Steps to reproduce:
Compile this piece of code:

```
    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        return;
    }
```

Visual Studio 2012 produce this unhelpful compilation error:

```
    Could not copy the file "<insert path of executable>" because it was not found.
```

Visual Studio 2010 produces this helpful compilation error:

```
    An object of a type convertible to 'string' is required
```

Visual Studio Versions:

- VS 2012: Version 11.0.50727.1
- VS 2010: Version 10.0.40219.1

We upgraded to JetBrains ReSharper 7.0.1 C# Edition at the same time as upgrading to VS 2012, but reproducing this while suspending ReSharper produces the same results.

Comment: When i tried with version 11.0.50912.1 i get :
"An object of a type convertible to 'string' is required"

Comment: VS2012 has exactly the same message... not sure what you've done, but no repro here.

Comment: Fine for me, Error 1 An object of a type convertible.  Are you sure you don't have a post build step creating this other error?

Comment: @JonasW, Marc and Justin, Thank you for trying to reproduce. Do any of you have ReSharper installed?

Comment: @JustinHarvey, to test, I created a new project in a new solution from scratch, not changing any settings nor adding post build steps.

Comment: When I compile the sources manually, then the correct error is shown. With "manually" I mean copying the csc.exe command and executing it in a command prompt.

When I compare the build output to what it should be, it looks like the csc.exe output and exit code are ignored. The build output should say

    The command exited with code 1.
  Done executing task "Csc" -- FAILED.

but it does say

  Done executing task "Csc". (TaskId:17)

Comment: Should I repost this question as "the csc.exe output and exit code are ignored by Visual Studio 2012"?

Comment: @JanVandenbussche I have the same issue, and I do have ReSharper installed, FWIW